# Modified breadth-first search on a graph with edge weights of 2, 3 or 5

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

> Suppose that we are given a directed graph H = (V, E). For each edge e, the weight of the edge, w(e) is either 2, 3 or 5. Modify the BFS so that it will compute the length of the shortest path from a single source vertex s. Explain why your algorithm is correct and determine its worst-case running time (You may assume that H is represented via an adjacency list).

How would you go about this? What makes the specific weight edges different from just any?

Comment: I've realized that the ideal path would be any immediate edge (u,v) if it's 2 or 3, and if it's 5 then the shortest path could possibly be a path with two edges of weight 2, so, unless the immediate edge is 2 or 3 (and exists at all), we'd need to check other routes in the adjacency list of the starting vertex.

I assume we'd just apply BFS normally, then determine the shortest path by tracing through once the other vertex desired is found. But I'm sure there's probably a better way to do it without adding extra lines outside of the search..

Comment: Are you familiar with Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: I'm at least aware of it. Yeah.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider imaginary nodes between the edges. So if between 2 nodes there is an edge of length 2. You make an intermediary node and add edges of length 1 between them. Then use the normal breadth first search. (You also need to do this for nodes of length 3 and 5, adding 2 and 4 nodes). Since you only add a O(E) nodes it's the same complexity.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you just make imaginary nodes such that every edge is the same length, then using the properties of BFS to tell you that once you encounter the node you're looking for - that's the shortest path. Then you could just have some unique property to those 'false' nodes so that you could easily determine which of the actual vertexes that are in the graph are part of the path. I'm still curious if there's any other way, however.